# What are the options to set base packaged directory for a package using sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to build a Debian package using sbt-native-packager as described in [this build.sbt](https://github.com/megamsys/megam_gateway/blob/master/build.sbt).

I set `appName` using

```
val appName = "megamgateway"
```

in [project/Build.scala](https://github.com/megamsys/megam_gateway/blob/master/project/Build.scala).

All works well. It is just that the contents are stored in `/usr/share/megamgateway`.

I'd like to have the contents under `/usr/share/megam/gateway`.

The only way I could find is to use

```
linuxPackageMapping
```

as shown [here](https://github.com/megamsys/megam_gateway/blob/444111d87ff2c53352028d06f21b7552e8ab78e6/build.sbt).

Before following along, I'd like to know about other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add to your project settings

```
name := "gateway"
defaultLinuxInstallLocation := "/usr/share/megam/"
```

Comment: It solves half the problem. The jars and such are moved under `/usr/share/megam/gateway`. But now my debian package name is "gateway" which we needs to `megamgateway`.

Comment: I changed to the following `name := "megamgateway"

defaultLinuxInstallLocation := "/usr/share/megam/"

defaultLinuxLogsLocation := "/var/log/megam"

linuxPackageMappings in Debian += packageTemplateMapping("/var/run/megam")()`. The install location changes, log location changes, but the pid location doesn't. Any idea how to tweak the package mapping for pid location ?

Comment: Unfortunately /var/run is hardcoded. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaServerApplication.scala

Comment: Yes. So i checked the code and added this `// === /var/run/app pid folder ===
  linuxPackageMappings <+= (normalizedName, daemonUser in Linux, daemonGroup in$
      packageTemplateMapping("/var/run/megam/" + name)() withUser user withGrou$
                }` But it now creates two directories /var/run/megamgateway and /var/run/megam/megamgateway. I am going to test it, and try adding a `rm /var/run/megamgateway`. That should fix this problem.